# Remote Desktop Connection Fails on Some Computers

Tags: windows-7, networking, remote-desktop, remote

**Issue**

Can't connect through RDC on most of our network PCs. The issue is recent, it used to work just fine on all PCs.

- OS: Windows 7 32/64bit

I can't make remote on most of them, but it's working on a small number of PCs. Nothing distinctive on these computers. While trying to connect I receive the following error message:

[image]

**What I've tried/checked**

- "Allow Remote Assistance connections to this computer" and "Allow connections from computers running any version of RD(less secure)" are both checked
- Ping doesn't work when I try to reach the problematic PCs.
- Firewall is disabled. Remote Desktop is allowed to communicate.
- Remote Desktop Service is started
- No antivirus installed
- Made sure Remote Desktop port is 3389, also tried to change to something else
- Tried to connect with the machine's name and IP
- regkey fDenyTSConnections is set to "0"
- No GroupPolicy to restrict access

---

**Question: Any ideas why I can't use remote anymore?**

Comment: Check the router rules, FW rules, etc. that may be physical in between based on your network setup then. It sounds like you've eliminated all OS level reasons why this would be happening, so now check your router and FW rules in between that routes the packets from one machine to the other. Check and confirm if the machines are on different subnets as well since if they're different, then it'd like be traffic that's routed so I'd check the router rules. Otherwise, double check one of the problem PCs again for the settings you itemize above just in case... triple confirm just in case....

Comment: Any update on this, anything determined with my suggestion by chance?

Comment: I wasn't able to check over the weekend, but I will do it this week and come back with some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Run a [TCP/UDP port scanner](https://www.adremsoft.com/netcrunch.tools/) and see if the ports are indeed open - and not just according to Windows.

I have a recollection that when plugged into a new wired network, Windows 7 briefly asks the user if Windows should trust this network as a work network, home network or public network. It never asks the user about this again. I know this changes the firewall settings, but I wouldn't be surprised if it also changes some other settings as well.

Comment: Please describe your relation with suggested site/software

Comment: I work as a support engineer for the company which makes the port scanner mentioned above.